# Sorting an array with a block in Squeak/Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I have a question in Smalltalk using `#sort:` with a block which I can't understand:

```
ArrayedCollection » sort: aSortBlock
    "Sort this array using aSortBlock for comparing elements.
     The block should take two arguments and return true if the
    first element should preceed the second one.
    If aSortBlock is nil then <= is used for comparison."
    Self mergeSortFrom: 1
    to: self size
    by: aSortBlock
```

What will be the results of:

```
| a b |
a := 10.
b := [:c :d | (c > a and: [d > a]) ifTrue: [c >= d] ifFalse: [c <= d]].
#(17 1 15 6 10 3 7 11 12 4) sort:b
```

Can someone please explain in details step by step?
At first `c = 17` and `d = 1`?
Both are not bigger than `a` (10) so does the block return `c <= d`?
What happens next? And how is the array actually being sorting?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger? Easiest way to understand what's happening with all the variables. The `a` to `d` naming of those variables makes this look very un-Smalltalk-y (yes, that's a word) and more like homework than a practical example.

Comment: it's not home work it's a sample from previous exams.... can you explain the logic please? just need the beginning....

Comment: The method you show uses the *merge sort* to sort the array. For details on that algorithm, you can Google "merge sort", or look at the source for `mergeSortFrom:to:by:`. The way any sort works is, at any step in the process, it's comparing two elements. Whether it's the first two (17 and 1 as you suggest) depends upon the algorithm. Regardless, the block you are passing (assigned to `b`) is how the sort will decide how a given pair of elements will be ordered. The block will be given two values and the first will be considered "smaller" if the block returns "true".

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments you could debug the `#sort:` method to see it work step by step. That is a good practice indeed and I also recommend you to do that.

However, debugging is easier if you first do two other things: (1) clearly express the intention of your code and (2) write some few Unit Tests to make sure your code corresponds with the intention. So, let's do that!

**Reveal you intention:**

In this case the intention is captured in the sorting block:

(c > a and: [d > a]) ifTrue: [c >= d] ifFalse: [c <= d]

which corresponds to:

*If both `c` and `d` are above `10` sort descending otherwise sort ascending*

**Write some tests:**

You already provided a sample, but let's add some simpler ones first

```
testAllAbove10
  self assert: (#(17 11 15 12) sort: b) = #(17 15 12 11)

testAllBelow10
  self assert: (#(1 6 10 3) sort: b) = #(1 3 6 10)

testMixed
  self
    assert: (#(17 1 15 6 10 3 7 11 12 4) sort: b) = #(1 3 4 6 7 10 17 15 12 11)
```

Should you now debug the `#sort:` method to see how it works? Well, yes, you could give the debugger a try at this point. However, in this case there is still a third thing you should to do first: study the sort algorithm from a book or online source. Once you have the theory clear, come back to the tests and debug them. It is by following all these steps that you would be able to really understand your code. At least, this is what good programmers do.